# why do i have to manually download the jars in maven2 repository when m2e already downloaded the pom and sha1

Tags: eclipse, maven, download

I've installed elcipse 3.6.2 and m2e plugin 
M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse (Incubation)    0.13.0.201105261543 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group.

I have imported an existing maven pom project. I right clicked on the project then went to 
Debug As > Maven Install.

It downloads most of the things but leaves out a lot of jar even though it's corresponding .pom and .sha2 are downloaded. So it leaves me with error messages like missing .jar.

So i had to download it manually from the ibiblio site.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?
BTW, the imported projects are from jetty 8.0.3M.
I don't think their pom needs changing.

I suppose it's in the eclipse/m2e plugin config?

Comment: Could you post the names of the missing jars? Sometimes maven is prevented from hosting the actual jar files them selves because of legal reasons.

Comment: You mentioned ibblio, but maven uses central (repo1.maven.org/maven2/) ...so may be you are using a different setup (settings.xml ?) Do you use Maven 3.0.X on command line? Have you tried to build your project on command line via mvn clean package ? Or mvn install without problems ?

Comment: I don't know why you people consistently using .sha2 when what i have in my dir e.g. .m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1 are these files: 
_maven.repositories
asm-3.1.jar.lastUpdated
asm-3.1.jar (had to download it manually)
asm-3.1.pom
asm-3.1.pom.sha1

i'm definitely missing something..?

also these..
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec/1.1.1/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar

i have in my settings.xml

Comment: ..
 <mirror>
  <id>ibiblio.org.pub.mirrors</id>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  <name>mirrors.ibiblio.org pub mirrors</name>
  <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url>
    </mirror>

 <mirror>
  <id>repo1.maven.org.maven2.mirrors</id>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  <name>asm</name>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
..

Comment: without the ; characters..sorry

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me almost always:

1. Delete your .pom and .sha2 files for the jar that is missing.
2. From Eclipse run the menu command "Update All Maven Dependencies" under Project.
3. This seems to download what is missing.

Hope that helps.